# Accessing field of a class in jstl if field is another class

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a bean classes:

```
public class Event{
    private Customer customer
    private String stringdate

    public Event(){}

    /*all getters and setters here*/
}

public class Customer{
    private int custId
    private String custname

    public Customer(){}

    /*all getters and setters here*/
}
```

Is there a way to display the content on a jsp page using JSTL?

Edit:
eventsView is a list of events passed in from a servlet. I could display the "cust" variable when it was a int field but when i changed it to a custom class Customer I am unable to display it as I get the exception below.

```
<c:forEach items="${ eventsView }" var="events" varStatus="index">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${ index.count }</td>
                        <td>${ events.customer.custid }</td>
                        <td>${ events.stringdate }</td>

                    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Thanks

The stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/CaspinolCustTest] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /event.jsp at line 32

29:         <c:forEach items="${ eventsView }" var="events" varStatus="index">
30:                             <tr>
31:                         <td>${ index.count }</td>
32:                         <td>${ events.customer.custId }</td>
33:                         <td>${ events.stringdate }</td>   

Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "customer"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:514)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:166)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:46)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:985)
    at org.apache.jsp.event_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(event_jsp.java:148)
    at org.apache.jsp.event_jsp._jspService(event_jsp.java:100)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: Use another dot. Did you even try?

Comment: Somehow EL thinks that test1 is a string. Look comment below.

Comment: What's `events`? Is it an array? If so, `customer` isn't a great numeric index. Without actual information, so far it looks like you're not iterating over what you think you are. You need to edit your question so it's cohesive, and complete.

Comment: Are you certain that `eventsView` is a list of `Event` objects?

Comment: Yes you are right. The reason it was throwing this exception was that my hibernate query was returning a List<Object> instead of List<Event>. Fixing that fixed the issue. Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

JSTL uses public getter methods. You need public methods: getCustomer(), getStringDate() in Event class and getCustId() in Customer class.

Comment: I have all the getters and setters in the classes. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<c:forEach items="${ class2List }" var="element" varStatus="index">
    <tr>
        <td>${ index.count }</td>
        <td>${ element.test1.foo }</td> <%-- calls element.getTest1().getFoo() --%>
        <td>${ element.test2.bar.baz }</td> <%-- calls element.getTest2().getBar().getBaz() --%>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Note that I renamed `list` to `element`, since the variable is an instance of Class2, and not a list. Also note that unlike in Java (where it would cause a NullPointerException), the EL will automatically evaluate the expression as `null` if one of the beans in the chain is null.

Comment: I kind o tried that already. I get java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "test1"

Comment: There is no way the above code throws such an exception. Show us the code of your classes, the code of your JSP, and the complete stack trace of the exception.